# При проверке clang-ом выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, qt, vim, clang

Если включить в .cpp файл QtWidgets, то при проверке синтаксе clang (clang_complete, vim) отметиться ошибка, при переходе по которой мы поподем в файл qglobal.h где написано:

```
#if !defined(QT_BOOTSTRAPPED) && defined(QT_REDUCE_RELOCATIONS) && defined(__ELF__) && \
(!defined(__PIC__) || (defined(__PIE__) && defined(Q_CC_GNU) && Q_CC_GNU >= 500))
#  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
     "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
#endif
```

Что это означает и почему на этом моменте clang видит ошибку?

Comment: clang "видит" ошибку, поскольку условие в `#if` истинно, далее срабатывает  директива `#error`, которую разработчики разместили в этом .h файле. Наверное надо последовать их рекомендации `"Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."`

Comment: @avp это понятно, но проверка, как я уже писал, происходит при проверке синтаксиса, а не компиляции... Вообщем как ее устранить?

Comment: @avp а, все, разобрался как устранить эту проблему! Спасибо, что указали про -fPIC - я и до этого видел, но раньше не приходило в голову поставить его в опции компилятору для проверки синтаксиса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, выражая благодарность avp, хочу оставить этот ответ, если у кого-то при программировании в vim возникнет подобная проблема. Для ее решения нужно просто указать clang-у, что проверка должна производится с опцией -fPIC. Для этого просто включаем в файл .clang_complete, который содержится в этой директории строку

```
-fPIC
```

После этого ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: Вообще-то, если хотите разобраться, то начните с того, что опция  [-fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967010/7286264) говорит компилятору, что надо делать позиционно-независимый код (и обычно используется при создании разделяемых библиотек (.so, .dll)). А `vim` (текстовый редактор) никакого отношения к данной проблеме не имеет.

Comment: @avp Слушайте, ну ведь в вопросе четко написано: "при проверке синтаксе clang (clang_complete, vim)" - тобишь: происходит проверка синтаксиса в редакторе vim с помощью плагина clang_complete, который, в свою очередь, использует clang. Соответственно, чтобы clang видел, что сдесь нужно использовать -fPIC мы указываем в конфигурационном файле то, что надо использовать -fPIC. Возможно вы не поняли, но проблема не на этапе компиляции!!! А проверки!

Comment: В самом деле, вы правы. Просто я никогда не использую подобные a'la IDE штучки

Comment: @avp ну да, такой подход не пользуется популярностью, хотя, как по мне, очень удобен. По крайней мере еще не встречал ситуаций, когда нельзя было бы обойтись без полноценной IDE.

Comment: Я вас понимаю. Наверное на начальном этапе подсказки IDE полезны. Потом они просто становятся не нужны. (*впрочем, я начинал еще с перфокарт (даже до АЦ-терминалов), когда еще и термина IDE не придумали, так что могу и ошибаться)*